# How to calculate Young's modulus of wood?

Tags: forces, elasticity

I'm attempting to calculate the modulus of elasticity, or [Young's modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_modulus), of various types of wood.

However, I'm confused by the `strain` component. It's calculated by the change in length divided by the original length.

I have various planks of wood and I want to see how much each bends under a known weight with one end of the plank fixed while the other has the weight attached. In this setup, what would the "original length" be? Or am I misunderstanding the formula?

Does Young's modulus only calculate the materials compression under load, meaning I'd have to apply the weight only the entire length of the plank of wood and see how much it compresses?

Edit: Based on the [article](https://www.doitpoms.ac.uk/tlplib/thermal-expansion/expt1.php) linked to by Farcher, I tried testing to see if the formula:

```
E = (4PL^3) / (dwh^3)
```

empirically made sense when calculating modulus of elasticity for a cantilever beam.

So I clamped a scrap of poplar wood to a table at its end. Measured the initial deflection from the table's surface with a micrometer. Then attached a 10 lb (44.48 N) weight to the end of the wood, and re-measured the deflection.

The change in deflection was 0.00018 meters. The distance from the table's edge to where the weight was hung was 0.183 meters. The width of the wood was 0.116 meters and the height was 0.06327 meters.

So if I put all those numbers into the equation, I get:

```
(4*44.482189159*0.183**3)/(.00018*.116*0.06327**3)
```

which equals `206193711` Pascals or `.21` GPa.

However, that value makes no sense. According to the [wood database](https://www.wood-database.com/balsa/), Balsa, one of the weakest woods there are, has a modulus of elasticity of `3.71` GPa.

I also have a sample of balsa, and my popular is objectively a lot stiffer and more rigid than it. I can literally snap the balsa in half with my bare hands where I can't with the poplar.

Why is my calculation so off? Is my equation incorrect, or have I made an error in my measurements?

Comment: Your setup is a cantilever beam. Look it up and you will find the formulas to apply. The deflection of the beam's end depends on the Young's modulus but in a slightly more complicated way.

Comment: [Experiment: Measurement of Young's modulus](https://www.doitpoms.ac.uk/tlplib/thermal-expansion/expt1.php)